# Toast String display object instead of Text

Tags: android, viewflipper, toast

In my code,I want to display **TextView** text name as Toast message.
I do following coding for that .I didn't get the proper text only object of that text I got.

In **Toast** I want to display the Text please guide me if possible.
Here is my code :

```
 package com.Viewflipper;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

    public class Viewflipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         Button next;
         Button previous;
         ViewFlipper vf;

         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
                 next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                 previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                 next.setOnClickListener(this);
                 previous.setOnClickListener(this);
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (v == next) {
                         vf.showNext();
                         Toast.makeText(this,vf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         **//HERE I DIDN'T GET vf.getText().toString();**

                 }
                 if (v == previous) {
                         vf.showPrevious();
                 }
         }
    }

**EDITED**


main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Next"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Previous"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a10" 
                    android:text="one"></TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a11"
                    android:text="two"></TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a12"
                    android:text="three">

                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a13"></TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a14"></TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/a15"></TextView>

            </ViewFlipper>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which text you want to display ??

Comment: I want to display my ViewFlipper TextView text..I am sharing my main.xml too.so you can get exactly idea about it...

Comment: just see that sir..after edited text you will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
   package com.Viewflipper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class Viewflipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     Button next;
     Button previous;
     ViewFlipper vf;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
             next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
             previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
             next.setOnClickListener(this);
             previous.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (v == next) {
                      vf.showNext();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView) vf.getCurrentView()).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             }
             if (v == previous) {
                     vf.showPrevious();
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: @dug939 and sunil_android  .
I used next.getTag().toString()..forced closed error.
and its next is my button ..I want data from **VIEWFLIPPER** textview.

I think as JoxTraex said I have to adaptermethod to call its text.
Guide me ..whatever your ans .I am going to accept your answ.

Comment: @user1197305 I Edit answer. please check it. messing getApplicationContext() ago in toast message

Comment: @dug939 Thank you for replying about my doubts .
Dude it only display next into next window.
I want to display text of My TEXTVIEW That is into the VIewflipper..
if possible guide me bro.

Answer (score 0):

A ViewFliper is an adapter.. you can't just grab it like that, you have to interact with the adapter and get the view and **THEN** grab the textview in that view.

Comment: ..I am displaying image like that ..so its work fine for me.
But I should get is its text part..
I am new to android could you please help me for that..

Comment: Learn how an adapter works, this is will help you. Do some research, google it. Then when you understand a bit of it, then you can handle the rest of the analysis.